# Calculation the number of State - refactor

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am implemented a logic to calculate the remaining Qty and Cost via `data` variable. It loop though each Product and calculate the remaining Qty left by counting the number of `Returned` Qty statuses and subtract with Product Qty.

Is there a way to refactor this code to look cleaner and understandable/maintainable?  I don't like the fact I have to do this: `obj[productItem.ProductId]` which look a bit ugly.

```js
const data = {Products: [{ProductId: 123,Qty: 5,Price: 50,State: [{Name: "Returned",Qty: 1},{Name: "Returned",Qty: 3}]},{ProductId: 123,Qty: 2,Price: 20,State:[{Name: "Returned",Qty: 1}]}]};


function getRemainingQty(order) {
    return order.Products.reduce((obj, productItem) => {
      let productStates = [];
  
      if (productItem.State) {
        productStates = productItem.State;
      }
      
      let returnedQty = productStates.reduce((quantity, productState) => {
        return productState.Name === "Returned" ? quantity + productState.Qty : quantity;
      }, 0);
  
      let returnRemainingQty = productItem.Qty - returnedQty;
      let returnAmountCost =  productItem.Price / productItem.Qty * returnRemainingQty;
  
      if (obj[productItem.ProductId]) {
        obj[productItem.ProductId].QtyRemaining += returnRemainingQty;
        obj[productItem.ProductId].ReturnCostRemaining += returnAmountCost;
      } else {
        obj[productItem.ProductId] = {
          QtyRemaining: returnRemainingQty,
          ReturnCostRemaining: returnAmountCost
        };
      }
  
      return obj;
    }, {});
  }


  console.log(getRemainingQty(data));
```

Comment: This might be more a more appropriate question over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some ideas, using destructuring, boolean `||`, `filter`, ...:

```js
const data = {Products: [{ProductId: 123,Qty: 5,Price: 50,State: [{Name: "Returned",Qty: 1},{Name: "Returned",Qty: 3}]},{ProductId: 123,Qty: 2,Price: 20,State:[{Name: "Returned",Qty: 1}]}]};

function getRemainingQty(order) {
    return order.Products.reduce((obj, { ProductId, Qty, Price, State } ) => {
        const returnedQty = (State || [])
              .filter(({ Name }) => Name === "Returned")
              .reduce((quantity, { Qty }) => quantity + Qty, 0);      
        const productStock = obj[ProductId] || (obj[ProductId] = {
            QtyRemaining: 0,
            ReturnCostRemaining: 0
        });
        const returnRemainingQty = Qty - returnedQty;
        productStock.QtyRemaining += returnRemainingQty;
        productStock.ReturnCostRemaining += Price / Qty * returnRemainingQty;
        return obj;
    }, {});
}

console.log(getRemainingQty(data));
```

Comment: Very nice. Not sure if destructuring, boolean || is readable to compare with my code. I guess it is subjective. How do you feel?

Comment: Indeed, I think it is a matter of opinion.